# android-studio : add libphonenumber library to project

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-studio-2.2

I want to add [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) library to my Android Studio project.

So, I added below line in my build.gradle(Module:app):

```
compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.6.1'
```

But this gives me error as below:

> Error:Could not find method compile() for arguments
>   [com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1] on
>   DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.android.support',
>   name='appcompat-v7', version='24.2.1', configuration='default'} of
>   type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.
>
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK
>   Manager. Open Android SDK Manager

Does anyone know the reason and solution ?

**build.gradle(Project:xxx):**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-rc2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(Module:app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.android"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

def SUPPORT_LIBRARY = "24.2.1"
def BUTTER_KNIFE_LIBRARY = "8.4.0"
def GLIDE_LIBRARY = "3.7.0"
def OK_HTTP_VERSION = "3.4.1"
def RETROFIT_VERSION = "2.1.0"
def GSON_VERSION = "2.7"
def FIREBASE_VERSION = "9.4.0"

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY"

    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$BUTTER_KNIFE_LIBRARY"
    apt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$BUTTER_KNIFE_LIBRARY"

    compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$GLIDE_LIBRARY"

    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$OK_HTTP_VERSION"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$OK_HTTP_VERSION"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:$GSON_VERSION"

    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$FIREBASE_VERSION"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:$FIREBASE_VERSION"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Note:** I ended up adding jars to `libs` folder from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/libphonenumber/libphonenumber/) (which I didn't wanted to do). If anyone knows how to accomplish this with using gradle, you are most welcome to answer.

Comment: Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager. Open Android SDK Manager to download it. This version is veryyyyyy new. Maybe the mirroring/distribution has not been completed.

Comment: put your project level .gradle  here

Comment: @Christopher yea.. my toolset is latest.. Studio, android tools, support libraries, and what not.. Any workaround ?

Comment: you have downloaded 24 sdk platform and tools ?

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ yes i have that too..

Comment: replace this def SUPPORT_LIBRARY = "24.0.2" @ChintanSoni

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ Why would I have to downgrade support library version ?